# How to load css in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, and I am using v.2.12. I am getting an error when I try to load the css from the external file.

I create the css folder inside the application folder. And I create the css file in the name of all.css.

In the view file I use the following code to link the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>css/all.css">
```

But the css file is not loading. I'm getting 404 error. Here is my configuration settings:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://webscarlets.com/ci/index.php';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Website Link: http://webscarlets.com/ci/index.php/welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function **base_url()** should return the base path (without index.php)

You may fix it by adding a backslash like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>/css/all.css">
```

or remove the index.php from your config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://webscarlets.com/ci/';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me try this and tell you

Comment: what is the URL printed out for CSS?

Comment: The folder CSS was not found on your server. Make sure you uploaded the CSS folder and all.css file

Comment: check out the link i have posted an another post

Comment: @Alaa Badran hi,when i use this i don't get my styles and also in my inspection on firebug,it shows that access forbidden,please help me...!!i'm trying it for 3 days:(

Comment: @Alaa Badranecho `link_tag('application/assets/css/style.css');` this is my header and `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/CodeIgniter-3.0.0/';` this is in my config

Comment: @papsk I think your problem is file permission. Please make sure the file is 755

Answer (score 34):

This is how you include CSS files in CodeIgniter:

```
<?php echo link_tag('css/mystyles.css'); ?>
```

That snippet will output this HTML:

```
<link href="http://site.com/css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

[The function `link_tag` is in the HTML helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/html_helper.html#link_tag), which must first be loaded.

(Note that you probably shouldn't put your CSS files in `/application/css`. It's just easier to put them in `/css` or maybe `/assets/css`.)

Answer (score 4):

I just find the solution to avoid index.php file and load ours CSS files.
Just copy the code below in a .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|styles|scripts|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Greeting!

Comment: The OP asked for a PHP / CodeIgniter way to load css.  Your response is unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

To attach a CSS, JS, Images .etc you just have to do is go to your **config** folder and write at the end of the **constant.php** file.

```
define('URL','ADD YOUR LOCAL/REMOTE PATH');

define('CSS',URL.'public/css/');
define('IMAGES',URL.'public/images/');
define('JS',URL.'public/images/');
```

After that goto your view and in the link just add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo CSS; ?>index.css">
```

this will solve your problem.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Add below line in your controller action /application/controllers/yourController.php

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then add below line to your view file's head tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url('assets/css/yourcssfile.css');?>" />
```

Assuming that you have assets/css/ folder is created in your app directory.

```
<path to your app folder>/assets/css
```

Answer (score 2):

before using the `base_url()` you should have to load the URL helper class.

something like `$this->load->helper('url');` in your controller

`base_url()` return you the path something like
    `'http://webscarlets.com/'`
if you have set it directly in the root or `'http://webscarlets.com/dir/'`

and also make sure about the location of your CSS file.

follow the link to know more about [URL Helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I loaded the base url helper
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','html');

Answer (score 2):

another way would be

define a constant in  constants.php (in config directory)

```
define("LAYOUT_URL","http://localhost/yoursite/css/");
```

"css" folder here i m assuming is inside application folder. NOw you can attach css in page like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo LAYOUT_URL;?>all.css">
```

Comment: but can you tell me why this is not working
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>/css/all.css">

Comment: define("LAYOUT_URL","http://localhost/yoursite/css/");
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo LAYOUT_URL;?>all.css">

I dont know this is proper way to access the css files?

Comment: I m not sure, but your base_url() is not loading your css file because of index.php in the config. It would likely search for the controller. My way is a clean way, there is nothing wrong with my way, it only matters if you're comfortable using it.

Comment: ok now check the link css is not loading. After adding the htaccess file to remove index.php from url css is not loading

http://webscarlets.com/ci/

now if i remove the .htaccess file css is working

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix it? here is my .htaccess code

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L] 

I added this htaccess script in the ci folder

Comment: Also i tried the code which is provided by the codeigniter user guide. it's working but css is not loading

Comment: use $this->config->base_url(); to load base_url

Comment: i'm getting the base url but the css is not loading. This is url i get
http://webscarlets.com/ci/css/all.css

Answer (score 2):

As **Jogesh_p**.

you use **base_url** as follow
put in controller (your controller)

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

in **controller** . 
if you want to use

as follow
put in where you want use base_url.

```
echo base_url()
```

NOTE: better you create new folder at root

(Example: theme) 
same: application, system, user_guide, theme)

i hope can you do

Answer (score 2):

Edit autoload.php as follows

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Then load css , js,image like that

```
img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/master.jpg"</img>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//config.php
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://webscarlets.com/ci/';
    $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

and try to load `css` by adding application folder

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<? echo base_url();?>application /css/all.css">`

**EDIT**

Here 
`base_url()` echos `'http://webscarlets.com/ci/'` then adding the file with path `application /css/all.css`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried as you said but it not working. What should i do next?

Answer (score 1):

Include `$this->load->helper('html');` in a controller function.

And use `linktag` key word in view file something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <?php echo link_tag('resources/style.css');?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    ....
    ?>
</body>
```

Here the resources is the folder that contain the style.css file.