# how load css in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

i have some code in codeigniter when i try to load css file is not working. how to load css in codeigniter and maybe my code its wrong. can you tell me ho to solve in my code?

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equivn="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Taekwondo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/tkd.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--head-->
        <div id="box-wrapper">
            <!--Header-->
            <header>
                <!--top info-->
                <div id="top-info">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="twelve column top-desc">
                            <ul>
                                <li><span>Login/Register</span></li>    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--top info end here-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <div class="twelve column">
                            <div id="left-header">
                                <!--logo start here-->
                                <div id="logo">
                                    <a href="home.php"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="main-logo" class="retina"></a>
                                </div>
                                <!--logo end here-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

controller code

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Home_c extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
}
```

?>

and my name css is tkd.css and i save in assets/css/tkd.css

Comment: what is the error you are getting? are you getting wrong path?

Comment: css is not working.. how to load css in codeigniter?

Comment: try my answer. If not working, then see your html source and check for css file path.

Comment: thanks you answer but when i try its not working. i has been check css file path in assets/css/tkd.css

Comment: No. I'm asking full path. View your source and check the link tag href.

Comment: full path in ta/assets/css/tks.css 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/tkd.css");?>">

Comment: Are you seeing this line in browser html source file?

Comment: No, i am sorry when i try see in browser fatal error in <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function base_url() in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\TA\application\views\home.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load css in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824555/how-to-load-css-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, I think you didn't load the url helper in application/config/autoload.php 
file.

```
$autoload['helper'] = array(('url');
```

Try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/css/tkd.css");">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo link_tag('css/mystyles.css'); ?>
```

That snippet will output this HTML:

```
<link href="css/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The function **link_tag** must be first loaded.

It can be found in HTML_HELPER

CREDITS :[Christian Davén](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12534/christian-daven)